# How to use nested loop using recursion and check the sum of digits in c++

Tags: c++, function

I want to calculate the number of occurence of a particular sum of digits in a k digit number. My code is

```
long recur(long k, long n)
{
    long count = 0;
    if(k == 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for(long i = 1; i <= 9 ; i++)
    {
        long c = i + recur(k - 1, n);

        if(c == n)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

/* k is the number of digits and n is the sum of digits i want to find. for example, if k is 3, then we can have numbers from 111 to 999 where sum of digits varies from 1+1+1=3 to 9+9+9=27.  If I want to find the number of k=3 digit numbers with sum(n)=4, then answer is 3. Because only 112,121 and 211 are possible solutions.*/

It is not giving me correct answer.The output always is 1. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this C or C++ code? Chose *one*, please.

Comment: Its in c++. I have changed the tagging to c++.

Comment: What incorrect result does it give you? And try to explain what your current code is supposed to do(comment your code).

Comment: @bkVnet I have finished editing. Hope it helps.

Comment: 400 is also a 3-digit number with sum 4.

Comment: @HappyCoder  I want to take only positive digits. Thats why I am iterating from 1 to 9.

Comment: 0 is a postive digit.

Comment: @BartvanNierop 0 is neither positive nor negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
long recur(long k, long n) {
    if(k==0) return n==0;

    long count=0;
    for(long i=1; i<=9; ++i) {
        count += recur(k - 1, n - i);
    }
    return count;
}
```